# d3js: make new parent data descend into child nodes

Tags: d3.js

I can't work out how best to pass changes to the data which occur at a parent node (e.g. an SVG `g` element) down to it's children (e.g. SVG `circle` elements).

I've read [this](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) and [this](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/) but still can't figure it out.

Here's a minimum working example. The example assumes you've got an object called `svg` which refers to a d3 selection containing an SVG element.

```
data = [{"id":"A","name":"jim"},{"id":"B","name":"dave"},{"id":"C","name":"pete"}];

g = svg.selectAll("g").data(data, function(d) { return d.id; }).enter().append("g");

g.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 3)
      .attr("cx", 100)
      .attr("cy", function(d,i) {return 100 + (i * 30);})

// The data gets passed down to the circles (I think):
console.log("circle data:");
d3.selectAll("g circle").each(function(d) { console.log(d.name); });     

// Now change the data, and update the groups' data accordingly
data = [{"id":"A","name":"carol"},{"id":"B","name":"diane"},{"id":"C","name":"susan"}];
svg.selectAll("g").data(data, function(d) { return d.id;});

// These are the results of the change:
console.log("after change, the group has:");
d3.selectAll("g").each(function(d) { console.log(d.name); });     
console.log("but the circles still have:");
d3.selectAll("g circle").each(function(d) { console.log(d.name); });
```

Can anyone help me find a concise way to get the new names into all the child elements of a group? In my real-life example, each `g` contains many `circle`s.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are 2 ways to propagate the data from parents to children:

1. [selection.select](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-select) will do this implicitly. (The implementations of `selection.append` and `selection.insert` are actually based on `selection.select` internally)

   ```
   svg.selectAll("g").select("circle")
   ```
2. You can explicitly redo the data join using a function to receive the parent data and return it in an array for the child.

   ```
   svg.selectAll("g").selectAll("circle")
       .data(function(d) { return [d]; });
   ```

These amount to the same thing.  The first option relies on some special behaviour in select so it can be a bit surprising at first, but it is nice in that it makes the pattern for node update symmetrical with the pattern for node creation via insert/append. The second option is useful if you need to apply any changes to the data as it is being propagated.

Here's another article you didn't link to that might be useful also: [Thinking with Joins](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. These work, but only for the first element in each `g`. 

If I add two circles to each group, only the first selected circle is updated with the new data.

Any idea why that could be?

Comment: If you have more than one circle you'll need to either handle each separately by classing them differently from each other and then doing select("circle.className") (or similar idea for second approach) to get at each one. If you have many circles in each g or a variable number you might consider using a full data join with nested data to create/remove the circles.

Comment: It doesn't seem such a crazy use case that one piece of data is represented by more than one SVG element. Shame there's no API way of doing this!

Comment: No, I agree it's not unusual.  But calling select once for each circle seems consistent to me considering you called append/insert explicitly once per circle to create them in the first place.  Matter of preference, I suppose.

Comment: Agreed. I think the 'more than one SVG element representing the same piece of data' thing is obviously an edge case. I rather think that the current behaviour, of updating the first element and not the others is 'odd' though. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I have been fiddling around for 3 days until I found this great answer. You are a genius

Comment: this is definitely harder than it should be. This answer and this page https://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/ helped.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you figured it out, but this is definitely not in the documentation. All of the documentation that deals with element grouping does not seem to deal with the child selection and data inheritance to children.

The answer is to use the [`.each`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-each) construct to update the children elements and append the children to the group enter() call.

```
data = [{"id":"A","name":"jim"},{"id":"B","name":"dave"},{"id":"C","name":"pete"}];

function draw(data) {
  var g = svg.selectAll("g").data(data, function(d) { return d.id; })

  genter = g.enter().append("g");

  // This is the update of the circle elements - 
  // note that it is attached to the g data, not the enter()
  // This will update any circle elements that already exist
  g.each(function(d, i) {
    var group = d3.select(this);
    group.select("circle")
    .transition() 
      .attr("r", 3)
      .attr("cx", 100)
      .attr("cy", function(d,i) {return 100 + (i * 30);})
  }

  // The data DOES get passed down to the circles, and the enter() statement
  // will create a circle child for each data entry
  genter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 3)
      .attr("cx", 100)
      .attr("cy", function(d,i) {return 100 + (i * 30);})
}

// Original drawing
draw(data);

// Now change the data, and update the groups' data accordingly
data = [{"id":"A","name":"carol"},{"id":"B","name":"diane"},{"id":"C","name":"susan"}];

// Second drawing, the SVG will be updated
draw(data);
```

Let me know if this works.

[This answer is based on some code grouping from this coderwall post: https://coderwall.com/p/xszhkg ]

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Scott Cameron answer, with the join syntax the answer would be:

```
const groups = svg.selectAll('g').data(data, (d) => d.id).enter().append('g');

groups.selectAll('circle')
      .data(d => [ d ])
      .join(
            enter => enter.append('circle')
                           .attr(...)
                           ...,
            update => update.attr('cx', (d) => ...)
                            .attr(...)
                            ...,               
      );
```

If you want to add another element to each group you can copy the 2nd block. You can even conditionally add the sub element:

```
groups.selectAll('rect')
      .data(d => someConditionHere ? [ d ] : []) // if we return empty array the element won't be added
      .join(
            enter => enter.append('rect')
                           .attr(...)
                           ...,
            update => update.attr('x', (d) => ...)
                            .attr(...)
                            ...,               
      );
```

you can find more informations about nested selections here: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/