# In d3.js, how can I preserve index i (or coerce / force group index j use in it's place) in data bindings subject to nested selections?

Tags: data-binding, d3.js, indexing

The context here is standard (index i based) data binding in d3.js, ie where indices have supposedly been preserved.

In my experience, selection mode, preservation of indices and data binding comprise a war zone. For all but the simplest cases, gain one and you lose one of the others.. (Bloggers, this an area which would benefit greatly from a **rigorous** truth table..).

For example, for nested selections of the form d3.selectAll()**.selectAll()**, the only index available at the point of data binding is that of the group or parentNode: **j**, which, though both common to old and new selections, cannot be used.

Assuming (because it finds only the first element **and** leaves all key/value pairs undefined) d3.selectAll().**select()** is **not** an option, is there some means of coercing binding based on the j index? Some kind of key function, perhaps, but specifying use of the index j?

In the past I've overcome this problem by playing selection & indexing leapfrog using object filters, but frankly it's messy and opaque.

Though possibly founded on misunderstanding (an obvious knock-on issue, for example, is where there are multiple elements at the given j index), glad of suggestions or insights..

Thug

Comment: As I've said in my comment to your previous question on the same subject, the D3 way is to rebind the data completely. It would help if you could add a concrete example where this is not possible or won't achieve what you want.

Comment: Catch22: obliged to use d3.selectAll().selectAll() to get the correct selection, which blocks any index-based data bind. Related question yes, same subject no. My previous question was about binding data at a specific index (which would work if i were available), this one is about how to switch indexes to allow data binding in the first place.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by index-based data bind.

Comment: By index-based, I'm referring to the (so-to-say standard) selection.data() binding, ie not modified by a key function. This is the case when only the first (ie value) argument is provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to believe, but in total it's taken me two weeks to find the [answer](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/): the so-called **descendent combinator "A B"**.

The description provided just enough of a hint to warrant a test..

Simply put, it preserves the index i of selected element A (and does so even where A and B are separated by multiple interstitial svg:g group elements). For example:

```
d3.selectAll(".parent_class .child_class");
```

Comment: The syntax for `select` and `selectAll` mirrors CSS3. (That would have been good to know in advance, right?)

Answer (score 0):

Using the selection's `.each()` method with an inline function is a way to access both child data and, via an outer scope, the parent's data. Something like this:

```
var parents = d3.selectAll('.parent-class').data(parentData)

parents.each(function(dParent, iParent) {

  var currentParent = d3.select(this)
  var children = currentParent
    .selectAll('.child-class')
    .data(dParent.children);

  // Now, e.g. if child color should depend on the parent data (and child data):
  children.attr('color', function(dChild, iChild) {
    // Here you have access to the parent's and the child's datums, 
    // as well as their indices
  });

});
```

Is this a solution to what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Very promising, but currently '.data(dParent.children);' provokes a 'ReferenceError: reference to undefined property dParent.children'. BTW, I also came across an [approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18831949/d3js-make-new-parent-data-descend-into-child-nodes) suggesting an explicit redo of the data join: 'd3.selectAll(".parent-class").selectAll(".child-class").data(function(d) { return [d]; });', but this leaves d.whatever undefined. That said, between my parents and currentParent lie several svg:g group layers: structurally the simplest possible, nonetheless multi-branched..

Comment: Oh, `dParent.children` is not anything built in. It assumes the parent data has some link to its children data, but should be replaced with whatever method you want to use to retrieve the child data. Also, note that in your example of using `data()` with a function as the first param, you have an opportunity to account for parent and child data (and indices) at once.